# start_with? for nil:NilClass undefined method expo-cli@2.9.0/src/commands/upload/utils.js

Tags: react-native, expo, testflight

I have built a react native app and have it working via expo and am using expo `build:ios` and expo upload:ios.  On upload it crashes with undefined method 'start_with?' for nil:NilClass in the utils.js for expo.

```
Error: undefined method `start_with?' for nil:NilClass
    at _callee2$ (/expo-cli@2.9.0/src/commands/upload/utils.js:53:11)
    at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:62:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:296:22)
    at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:114:21)
    at step (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:17:30)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:28:13
```

Expo diagnostics:

```
Expo CLI 2.9.0 environment info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 10.14.3
      Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/sh
    Binaries:
      Node: 10.15.1 - /usr/local/bin/node
      npm: 6.4.1 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    IDEs:
      Xcode: /undefined - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      expo: ^32.0.0 => 32.0.4 
      react: 16.5.0 => 16.5.0 
      react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz => 0.57.1 
      react-navigation: ^3.0.9 => 3.1.4 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      expo-cli: 2.9.0
```

I have never uploaded an app before so I don't have any idea what the solution would be if its my code,  the build,  the software installed.

Comment: I have the same issue, I can't seem to fix it no matter what I do include ezedeptris'd comment. I have xcode in the application folder and I've ran it many times using different projects. I also don't have a beta version. Did you fix it Baron?

Additionally I set my environment variables but expo still won't debug which is a different issue and equally as frustrating.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, the problem was

```
IDEs:
      Xcode: / undefined - / usr / bin / xcodebuild
```

if you never executed xcode you must run it, load some project, run simulator, or something like that, but if you downloaded some beta version and you paste the beta into application's folder like me, my solution was change the xcode name from `xcode-beta` to just `xcode` and that's all

another problem could be that you did not have the xcode into the application folder

i hope this helps you